# Using $.each loop to create multiple divs, not working

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

I've got a php page setup as follows:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        // Validate results and if correct insert into the DB
        // Else add the respective errors
        $data[0]['error_1'] = 'Error_1_text';
        $data[0]['error_2'] = 'Error_2_text';
        /*
        .
        .
        .
        */
        $data[0]['error_n'] = 'Error_n_text';
        print_r(json_encode($data[0]));
    }
?>
```

This is where the following AJAX request sends a POST request. If the entered form is valid it is inserted into DB else if it has any error(s) all the errors are appended to the array index `$data[0]`, and finally the array is `json_encoded`, and `print_r()`ed.

```
<body>
    <div class="ssss"></div>
</body>
<script>
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost/path/to/above/file",
        method: "POST",
        data: {
            submit: 'yes',
            form_data_0: 'form_text',
            form_data_1: 'form_text',
            form_data_2: 'form_text'
        },
        success: function(data){
            // Code to check if errors were present
            result = JSON.parse(data);
            if (result.hasOwnProperty('0')) {
                $.each(result['0'], function(key, error) {
                    let x = 0;
                    // Display each error into a modal
                    $("div#ssss").html('<div id="dmessage_' + x + '" class = "modal" style="display:block"><p id = "pmessage_' + x + '">' + error + '</p></div>');
                    x++;
                });
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

On success of the AJAX request, the `data` is `JSON.parse()`d and this result is assigned to a variable `result`. Then we check if there were any errors during the post-processing of the form. using `if (result.hasOwnProperty('0'))`, if so, the aim is to display each error in a `<p>error</p>` with a dynamic id enveloped in a `<div>` with a dynamic id. 
To achieve this I created a `$.each()` loop and initiated a variable `x = 0`. Now we loop over the contents of the `$.each()` loop, where we intend to display a `<div></div>` with contents shown in the code along with the `error` text being sent over by PHP from the back-end and the id being `dmessage_` concatenated with the current value of `x`. Once done, we increment `x` and loop over again for the next error. 
However what happens is, only 1 error-box is displayed, no-matter how many errors are being sent by PHP. I confirmed that by adding the following piece of code inside the `if()` statement:

```
let array = [];
$.each(result['0'], function(key, error) {
    // Display each error into a modal
});
array[x] = array.push(error);
console.log(array); // Displays all the errors correctly inside the console
```

Also thing worth noting is that although only one error-box is displayed all are created for each error. I confirmed that by `console.log()`ging `$().html()` this piece of code[image: console shows three objects being created], 
 however the elements tab in developer tools along with the browser display window shows only one error-box[image: Elements shows only one].

Comment: Don't `print_r` your PHP response, but `echo` it. Your Javascript expects JSON.

Comment: @Michael I tried but that doesn't help.

Comment: "Doesn't help" in what way?

Comment: Your `x` is initiating to `0`. Use `key` variable instead of `x`

Comment: @Michael that doesn't solve my problem, I get only one div

Comment: @RiteshKhandekar Thank you that indeed solves my problem.

Comment: Perhaps the last one. In each iteration using ` $("div#ssss")`.html(), it completly swaps and left nothing from before

Comment: @sonic Yes I realized it I've changed that to `.append()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**<sup>I know you got a solution but I will post my answer</sup>**

**1st:** `echo json_encode`

<s>**2nd:** You return `$data[0]` from PHP .. that mean the array will looks like</s>

`['error_1' => 'Error_1_text' , 'error_2' => 'Error_2_text' , ......]`

**3rd:** On success function You loop through `result[0]` which will be in this case = `'error_1' => 'Error_1_text'`

**4th:** No need to use `x` at all you can directly use `key`

**5th:** You can directly use `dataType: 'json'` instead of `JSON.parse(data)`

**6th:** change `.html(` to `.append(`

Consider all of the above then your code should looks like

php

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        // Validate results and if correct insert into the DB
        // Else add the respective errors
        $data['error']['error_1'] = 'Error_1_text'; // change all `$data[0]` to `$data['error']` it will be much easier 
        $data['error']['error_2'] = 'Error_2_text';
        /*
        .
        .
        .
        */
        $data['error']['error_n'] = 'Error_n_text';
        echo(json_encode($data));  // <<<< just $data here
    }
?>
```

JS

```
<body>
    <div class="ssss"></div>
</body>
<script>
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost/path/to/above/file",
        method: "POST",
        dataType : 'json',  //<<<<< here
        data: {
            submit: 'yes',
            form_data_0: 'form_text',
            form_data_1: 'form_text',
            form_data_2: 'form_text'
        },
        success: function(data){
            // Code to check if errors were present
            if (data.error) {   //<<<<< here
                $.each(data.error, function(key, error) {
                    // Display each error into a modal
                    $("div#ssss").append('<div id="dmessage_' + key + '" class = "modal" style="display:block"><p id = "pmessage_' + key + '">' + error + '</p></div>');
                });
            }else{
               $("div#ssss").html('');
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This solves my problem:

```
<script>
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost/path/to/above/file",
        method: "POST",
        data: {
            submit: 'yes',
            form_data_0: 'form_text',
            form_data_1: 'form_text',
            form_data_2: 'form_text'
        },
        success: function(data){
            // Code to check if errors were present
            result = JSON.parse(data);
            let x = 0;
            if (result.hasOwnProperty('0')) {
                $.each(result['0'], function(key, error) {
                    // Display each error into a modal
                    $("div#ssss").append('<div id="dmessage_' + x + '" class = "modal" style="display:block"><p id = "pmessage_' + x + '">' + error + '</p></div>');
                });
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```